# Calling bootbox with bootstrap 3 modal open makes bootstrap modal lose focus when bootbox gets closed

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootbox

Open a bootbox dialog from inside a bootstrap modal.

When closing that bootbox, the bootstrap modal loses focus and the scroll now scrolls the page behind the modal, and not the modal itself. (So scrolling scrolls the body, and not the modal itself).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like when closing a modal there is no check to open modals before removing "modal-open" from the DOM body. Will also investigate if this is an open issue in bootstrap's repo and migrate the issue over.

I've hacked it in my app by adding a check to see if there are any open modals, if there are re-adding modal-open to body:

```
dialog.on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  if($('.modal.in')){
    $('body').addClass('modal-open');
  }
});
```

Comment: Multiple open modals is not really supported by Bootstrap, which by extension means Bootbox doesn't play nicely with having other modals open.